# Como executar uma mesma query para "ids" diferentes

Tags: mysql, pdo

Possuo um array com os seguintes IDs:

```
Array ( [0] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 3 ) Array ( [0] => 5 )
```

A consulta deverá retornar todos os valores encontrados para estes IDs, sendo assim, como ficará a montagem da `query` [utilizando PDO]?

Comment: Não entendi, você quer a lógica para o banco de dados ou para o código do php?

Comment: Os  dois, rsrs. @Francisco

Comment: `select * from table where id in (x,y,z)` ,utilizando o [IN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deve ter alguma maneira mais fácil, não sei, mas você pode fazer isso com o `implode()`:

**Utilizando o `OR`:**

```
$ids = implode(" OR ID=", $array); //Concatena os arrays com uma string no meio de cada

$query = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE ID=$ids"; //Query a ser executada

$conn->query($query); //Executando a query ($conn é a variável de conexão)
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/g5coNb).

**Utilizando o `IN`:**

```
$ids = implode(",", $array);

$query = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE ID IN ($ids)";

$conn->query($query);
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/4Lt2Nv).