# Passar um php array numa query e retornar vários resultados

Tags: php, sql, array, query, mysqli

Quero passar um POST array dinâmico do tipo:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "3" }
```

Para uma SQL query em que retorna vários resultados consoante os valores das strings no array

```
Select nome, count(avaliacao) FROM tabela WHERE '1'
Select nome, count(avaliacao) FROM tabela WHERE '2'
```

E o resultado da query vai ser:

> Array(2) ( [resultado 1] => 10, [resultado 2] => 13 )

Já tentei com o `implode` e o SQL `IN` mas retorna somente o total do `count` de 1 e 3.

Comment: Você deveria pensar em uma lógica de escrita da linha sql, para concatenar todos os valores do array

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como executar uma mesma query para "ids" diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/232121/como-executar-uma-mesma-query-para-ids-diferentes)

Comment: @Francisco, o que eu quero é um pouco diferente. Eu quero uma consulta por cada resultado... Eu já utilizei o SQL IN e o resultado é o count de 1 e 3 e não o count de 1 e o count de 3.

Comment: Ta muito mal explicado, não consigo entender o que quer... Explique o porque você quer fazer isso.

Comment: @Francisco quero construir gráfico a partir da informação múltipla seleccionada no form que tenho atrás.

Comment: O `IN` parece ser bem viável para você. Caso esteja com dúvida, veja [esse exemplo](http://www.ebrueggeman.com/phpgraphlib/documentation/tutorial-mysql-and-phpgraphlib).

Comment: Também só consigo ver o `in` como solução, então acredito que será melhor você editar a pergunta e adicionar a estrutura da tabela, exemplos de registros presentes nela e qual seria o resultado esperado. Da forma que está não ficou suficientemente clara a pergunta.

Comment: Tenta agrupar também a consulta pelos campo relevantes. Ex: `Select nome, count(avaliacao) FROM tabela WHERE id IN (1,2,5,10) GROUP BY nome`

Comment: @rray a sua resposta, já mudou o panorama e mostrou quase uma aproximação do resultado esperado. Falta a hierarquia de netos até ao avó. Porque no IN é uma variavel que varios valores e quero que retorne o valor dos mesmos. O problema é que uma tabela tem a definição da hierarquia do avó até aos filhos e netos. E na outra tem a contagem para o resultado final para o id correspondente. Esse id é o id correspondente ao que foi introduzido na db.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que você deve alterar a query para realizar somente uma consulta e trazer todos os resultados que você precisa.

Outro detalhe falta o nome da coluna ali no where, mas vou considerar que tenha esquecido de colocar somente aqui na pergunta.
Tente isto:

```
SELECT 
    nome, count(avaliacao) 
FROM 
    tabela 
WHERE 
    nomeColuna in('1','2') 
GROUP BY 
    nome;
```

Comment: Agora estou com um problema.   query = "SELECT  a.menuNome as nome, COUNT(DISTINCT b.id_avaliacao) as TEMA FROM menu a INNER JOIN respostas b ON (a.menuId = b. menuId) WHERE b.menuId IN (SELECT m3.menuId from menu m3 WHERE m3.menuIdPai in (SELECT m2.menuId from menu m2 WHERE m2.menuIdPai in (select m3.menuId FROM menu m3 WHERE m3.menuId IN ('".implode("','",$id)."')))) GROUP by menuNome"; Isto esta a retornar para cada filho o numero de ocorrencias. No qual no $id é o numero de ocorrencias do avo(raiz).